# Remove a root tag from xml/html using tostring() of lxml

Tags: python, lxml, cdata

How to make a html text without a root tag (usually it's `<html></html>`)? To example, for use in CDATA:

```
<![CDATA[<div class="foo"></div><p>bar</p>]]>
```

My code:

```
from lxml import etree

html = etree.Element('root')
etree.SubElement(html, 'div', attrib={'class':'foo'})
etree.SubElement(html, 'p').text='bar'

t = etree.tostring(html)
# '<root><div class="foo"/><p>bar</p></root>'
```

I would not want to use regex to remove the root tag.

Comment: But is just a matter of printing? As far as i know, `etree.Element` need to have a root tag, you cannot remove it.

Comment: Why do you want to remove the root element? If you want to create a CDATA section, use [`etree.CDATA`](https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree.CDATA-class.html).

Comment: It will do `<![CDATA[<root><div class="foo"></div><p>bar</p></root>]]>`, but some web-services will not accept extra tag.

Comment: Other often case, when need get from some three-party html pages only text with text formatting tags (`<b>`, etc), without structurial tags of pages which will only trash. To save such the formating tags need use `tostring()`, and then the mentioned regexp. This make a confusing code with parsing html/xml, regexps, text/xml convertations forward and backward...

Answer (score 1):

If you need the text representation of all subelements without the root element, you can do:

```
subels = ''.join([etree.tostring(el).decode('ascii') for el in html])
```

where `html` is the `Element` of your question. In this case `subels` is a string:

```
'<div class="foo"/><p>bar</p>'
```

This can be further improved to get only specific tags using the `iter` method. For example:

```
subels = ''.join([etree.tostring(el).decode('ascii') for el in html.iter('div', 'p'])
```

will return only the `'div'` and `'p'` tags, so if there had be other tags they would have been omitted.
You can use it to filter out unwanted tags, but just be careful because it may broke the document hierarchy: it still returns children tags of undesired tags.

#### EDIT after comments

If the root tag has a text attibute which you want to keep, just add it back.

```
subels = ''.join([html.text] + [etree.tostring(el).decode('ascii') for el in html])
```

Comment: Thank you. Though it also remove the text of root, which on same level that sibling tags. E.g. `''.join([etree.tostring(el).decode('ascii') for el in etree.fromstring('<root>Some <b>bold</b> text</root>'))` → `<b>bold</b> text`.

Comment: Using `.decode('ascii')` produced weird output in my case. `etree.tostring(el, encoding='unicode', pretty_print=True)` worked well.